Using logging in python unit tests to get warnings
I'm trying to add some logging to unit tests so it's not ideal to add a logger to every module or file. I just need to know when a warning from some called function pops up in a sub module/test. These warnings would get printed to the console as well if that helps.
My file structure looks something like this:
test runner 
- create logger 
- call sub module 1 
sub module 1 
- tests 
- calls sub module 2 
sub module 2 
- deprecation warning

Currently I have a logger like this, but it can only catch warnings that are in the same file:
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.WARNING, format=format)

logger_file_handler = logging.RotatingFileHandler(logfile)\
logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.captureWarnings(True)        
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

root_logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

warnings.warn(u'Warning test')

I've seen some things saying I need to create a logger in each file for the warnings to bubble up to the root logger. Is that the only way?
